# Understanding Python async / await compared with Node js async / await

Tags: python, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm learning asynchronous programming in Python. I wrote some code to simulate fetching urls in Python and Node; the results are different and I'm not sure why.

**Python**

```
async def asyncFunc():
   await asyncio.sleep(3)
   print('woke up...')

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task( asyncFunc() ) for i in range(3)]

    for task in tasks:
        await task
        print('done waiting...')

asyncio.run(main())
```

**results:**

```
woke up...
woke up...
woke up...
done waiting...
done waiting...
done waiting...
```

**Node**

```
const asyncFunc = async () => {
  await mySleepFunction(3);
  console.log('woke up...');
}

const main = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    await asyncFunc();
    console.log('done waiting...');
  }
}

main();
```

**results**

```
woke up...
done waiting...
woke up...
done waiting...
woke up...
done waiting...
```

The Node results are what I expected. My understanding is that the tasks created by `create_task` do not start executing until they are awaited (in the for loop); but how does the for loop advance to begin execution of the second task if the first task has not yet completed?

thanks for your help on this one

Comment: Note that if you, in the Node.js version, create the "task" (`Promise`) first, add it to an array, then await it in a loop, the result would be the same.

Comment: thanks for the insight. I think the difference has something to do with the fact that in Node promises are "eager."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My confusion came from not realizing that `create_task` is used to [start coroutines running concurrently](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html). The Python code could be modified so that it gives the Node results by omitting the `create_task` and instead just awaiting the task:

```
async def main():

  for task in tasks:
      await asyncFunc()
      print('done waiting...')
```

Using `create_task` is similar to using `Promise.all` on an array of promises in Node.js

Comment: Just a note here: consider following Python coding guidelines while using Python and other languages' guidelines accordingly. `asyncFunc` name should be translated to `async_func` in the Python world